# Batch insertion issue while shutting down camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am doing batch insertion in mysql using mybatis.I keep adding messages to an ArrayList and fire the query when ArrayList size has reached the batch size.

```
<route  id="billingRoute">
<from uri="activemq:queue:{{billing.queue}}" />
<log message="Message received from billing queue is ${body}"></log>
<unmarshal ref="gsonBilling"></unmarshal>
<bean beanType="com.bng.upload.processors.GetCdr" method="process(com.bng.upload.beans.BillingEvent,${exchange})" />
log message="Multicasting  data ${body} to file system and database" />
<multicast>
<pipeline>
<transform>
<method ref="insertionBean" method="billingBatchInsertion"></method>
</transform>
<choice>
<when>
<simple> ${body.size()} == ${properties:batch.size}</simple>
<to uri="mybatis:batchInsertBilling?statementType=InsertList"></to>
<log message="Inserted in billing table : ${in.header.CamelMyBatisResult}"></log>
</when>
</choice>
</pipeline>
<pipeline>
<choice>
<when>
<simple>${properties:billing.write.file} == true</simple>
<setHeader headerName="path">
<simple>${properties:billing.cdr.folder}</simple>
</setHeader>
<log message="Going to write to file : ${body}"></log>
<bean beanType="com.bng.upload.processors.ToFile"
method="process(${exchange},com.bng.upload.beans.BillingCdr)" />
<to uri="file://?fileExist=Append"></to>
</when>
</choice>
</pipeline>
</multicast>
</route>
</routeContext>
```

We are not using transactions as there are  multiple components included in route -Files,ActiveMq and Database. The issue is that when the tomcat is restarted,if the ArrayList size has not reached the batch size,those messages get lost.Is there any solution to it ?

Comment: Not sure I understand, you want to maintain a state, even after tomcat, which is hosting Camel is restarted? Basically you want to continue where you left off even after a restart?

Comment: Yes we wanted to do that.Now we are saving the list in redis till it gets inserted in db.